# Geometric visualization of ${z^n}$ complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $\gamma : [0,2\pi] \to \Bbb C$ the closed path defined by $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$. We consider the following integral for $n \in \mathbb Z$ :
$$\oint_\gamma z^n dz $$

I already know the result, by computation, we have that :

If $n\neq -1$ then $\oint_\gamma z^n dz =0 $

If $n=-1$, $\oint_\gamma z^n dz =\oint_\gamma \frac1z=2\pi i$

I wanted to know what does it "geometrically" mean ? I heard about a hole in the loop for the case $n=-1$, but to me $\frac1z$ and $\frac{1}{z^2}$ have both this discontinuity and same properties in general, why is the integral different ? What makes the case $n=-1$ different from the others ?

Comment: $\frac{1}{z^2}$ has a primitive in $\mathbb C^*$ but $\frac{1}{z}$ does not.

Comment: Indeed but this answer can be given only after knowing about primitives in $\Bbb C$. I was wondering if we could give an answer (geometric maybe?) that does not rely on primitives.

Comment: To me, the calculation _is_ the explanation: If $\gamma$ is a piecewise-smooth path starting at $1$, ending at $z$, and not passing through $0$, we can define $$F_{n,\gamma}(z) = \int_{\gamma} w^{n}\, dw.$$This is a well-defined function of $z$ (i.e., independent of $\gamma$) if and only if the integral of $w^{n}\, dw$ about the unit circle vanishes, and in this case gives a primitive of $f(z) = z^{-n}$. <> Perhaps you're looking for (something related to) the interpretation of $\exp:\mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{C}^{\times}$ as the universal cover in the sense of topology...?